# How to place images , which have been rotated with 90 degrees to fit a div container like before and the other images?

Tags: html, css

I have an image gallery with many images in it, but some of them needed to be rotated, as when uploaded they were rotated to the left.

Initially I have set the CSS of the `div` containers where every image is in separate div with the same class. But once I have rotated them with additional CSS on appending to the DOM `if image rotation is "some value" - > rotate with 90 degrees` ( with `transform` css property).

And now those images when the window is resized are going outside of the div containers and the other ones resize to fit the containers. This is probably because of the fact that when the images are rotated the `width` becomes `height` and the `height` becomes `width` . I know i have not made `@media queries` , but i want to achieve for now the images to fit their containers. What is the best approach and solution ?

```css
#imageContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.imgBox {
  float: left;
  width: 31.33%;
  border-style: groove;
  border-color: dimgrey;
}

#imageContainer img {
  width: 90%;
  height: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  object-fit: inherit;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  align-content: inherit;
}

#imageContainer p {
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Arial Black";
}

.rotate90 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="imageContainer">
  <div class="imgBox">
    <img id="image_id_002" alt=" " src="....." class="rotate90">
    <p>Image Title</p>
  </div>
  <div class="imgBox">
    <img id="image_id_002" alt=" " src="......">
    <p>Upside-down look</p>
  </div>
  <div class="imgBox">
    <img id="image_id_002" alt=" " src="......" class="rotate90">
    <p>Image Title</p>
  </div>
  <div class="imgBox">
    <img id="image_id_002" alt=" " src="...... ">
    <p>Image Title</p>
  </div>
  </div
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use a square containers, so that insides could be rotated anyhow.
Maybe, overflow:hidden, to crop images for better view.

Comment: What exactly should i change to make them square ? `Overflow:hidden` on the `#imageContainer img`  ?

Comment: You can try `width: 31.33vw; height: 31.33vw;` for `.imgBox` if you have a full width parent div - to keep proportions on resize.

Comment: Overflow:hidden , keeps them in the div container ;) .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rotating the content, rotate the container (in this case, rotate that .imgBox). If you don't do this, as they said, make that container a fixed square, one way of doing responsive and dynamic squares is grid.

Comment: Yes i will make it either with Grid or with Flexbox